# Uploading multiple documents into a library keeps the documents checked out and not visible to other users

Tags: document-library, versioning

When you upload multiple documents into a Document Library with versioning turned on, is it a SharePoint 2007 default to keep the documents checked out?  For some reason, when multiple documents are uploaded to a document library it doesn't give it a version and keeps the documents checked out to the user that uploaded them.  The way it's working is no one can see any of the documents given there is no inital version.  The only one that can see the documents is the person who uploaded them.  When I looked, I noticed they were checked out to the user that uploaded them.  I would think it should function pretty much the same as uploading a single document, where it prompts you for the initial check in after it's uploaded.

If this is a setup issue, is there a way to automatically have the multiple documents uploaded checked in after they are uploaded?  Or, is this normal behavior and the users will have to remember to check in the multiple documents after they are uploaded?

Thanks in advance,
Robert

Comment: Have you tried it without check-in required or toggling the major, minor version handling?

Answer (score 2):

SP 2010:
Go to Document Library Settings -> Versioning Settings -> Require Check Out Set to no

MOSS 2007:
Document Library -> Settings -> Document Library Settings -> Versioning settings -> Require Check Out Set to no

Also follow this [link](http://sharemypoint.wordpress.com/2007/12/20/automatically-checkin-files-after-uploading/) to have more idea

Comment: Thanks for the replies.  Changing the "Require Check Out" to "no" in the document library worked.  Thank you very much for the assistance...  Much appreciated...

Comment: Pleasure to be helpful :).

Answer (score 1):

This is because of having mandatory fields in your Document Library.
When you have fields (i.e. Columns) that are mandatory and you upload multiple files, these mandatory columns do not get filled and hence the files are checked out by default.

**Quick Solution:** Make all mandatory fields (except Name ofcourse) "not required" and try upload multiple files. You will not have the files checked out by default.

Answer (score 0):

Yes that is the default behavior when versioning is enabled in a library.

Comment: The only other question I have is with the "Require Check Out" option set to "No"; people can edit documents without them being checked out.  After they do their edits, will SharePoint require them to check in a major or minor version?  Given the document was never checked out to edit, how will it impact versioning with this option set to "no?"

Comment: When require check out is set to no, people can edit the items without them being checked out.  If versioning is enabled, it should ask them if it's a major or minor version when they upload the new copy.  I typically feel that if major and minor versioning are going to be used that check out should be required, or else you run into upload collisions and missing data when multiple people try to edit the document in short order.

Comment: During the document library creation, if I choose "Yes" in the "Create a version each time you edit a file in this document library?" option and set the "Require Check Out" option to "No" in the versioning settings, would the same thing happen in regards to upload collisions and missing data as you described above?

Comment: Even if the documents aren't required to be checked out for editing, but the other setting creates a new version when a document is edited, wouldn't the versioning with the document library creation setting handle the collisions and missing information?

Comment: It doesn't do merges, so if User A starts editing a version with Paragraphs 1, 2 and 3 in it and decides to delete paragraph 2, if user B opens the file before any changes are saved back, he'll see paragraphs 1, 2, and 3.  If user A saves the file before user B finishes, the current version will have paragraphs 1 and 3.  User B makes minor edits to paragraph 1 and saves the file.  You're back to paragraphs 1, 2, and 3 again.  Forcing check out is the only way to remedy that.

Comment: Ok, thanks for the clarification. Looks like I am going to have to have the users remember to check in their documents when they upload multiple documents.

Thanks again for your help...  
Robert

Comment: PirateEric, your primary answer is incorrect. "Check-out upon bulk-upload" is not a standard behaviour when versioning is turned on. Instead check-out is caused by mandatory fields without a default value. Maybe you'd like to correct this in order to make the post more reliable?

Answer (score 0):

As an addition to Satish Surath's (correct) answer:

**Assigning a default value** to all of your mandatory metadata fields before bulk-uploading your files will also avoid unwanted check-outs. If you procede like this, you don't have change your column settings to "optional".

You can choose between these two approaches depending on whether or not there are sensible default values for the documents you are about to upload.

Comment: An addition should be added as a comment and not a new answer

Answer (score 0):

One of your content types may have required field, especially default content type "Document".
I changed required field to optional and it worked for me.